# How to print every user input in python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to get Python to print every user input on a while loop. Essentially the user enters a value, then is asked again and again for a value until user decides to stop entering values. The code prints the sum of the values but also each individual value inputted.

I managed to get everything working except printing each individual value. Any help is really appreciated!

```
another = True
init_bal = 1000
deposit = 0

while another:
    another += 1
    deposit += int(input("Enter amount: "))
    print(f'${deposit} deposited!')

    another = int(input("Make another deposit? Yes=1, No=2 "))
    if another == 1:
        another = True
    else:
        print(f'Your initial balance was ${init_bal}.')
        print(f'You have deposited a total of ${deposit}.')
        print(f'Your final balance is ${init_bal + deposit}.')
        break
```

Comment: The code looks ok, what is the behavior you're experiencing? Are you asked always the deposit question? After how many values does it stops printing?

Comment: what do you mean?  It seems like it's working fine

Comment: It should stop printing when the user has no more 'deposits' to make, which it does. When the user chooses '2', the program ends. However, i can't figure out a way to print every value (deposit) the user inputs. For example, the final output should be:

Your initial balance was $1000
You have deposited $100, $50, $25 (it's doesn't have to be exactly like this, but the point is to get it to print every value inputted by the user)
Your final balance is $1175

Comment: you mean your last 10 transactions like that?

Comment: @ anon01 @ Maran Sowthri @Uriya Harpeness

The final output should be: Your initial balance was $1000 You have deposited $100, $50, $25 (it's doesn't have to be exactly like this, but the point is to get it to print every value inputted by the user) Your final balance is $1175

Comment: @RobinSage append your input values to a list and print the list once you are done.

Comment: @NineTails Yeah, someone just answered it... I feel so stoopid for not remembering the obvious... many thanks!!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
from datetime import datetime

init_bal = 1000
deposit = 0
transactions = []

while True:
    deposit += int(input("Enter amount: "))
    print(f'${deposit} deposited!')
    transactions.append({'time': datetime.now(), 'amount': deposit})

    try:
        another = int(input("Make another deposit (Yes=1, No=any)?"))
    except:
        break
    
    if another != 1:
        break

print(f'Your initial balance was ${init_bal}.')
print(f'You have deposited a total of ${deposit}.')
print('Your transactions history:')

for transaction  in transactions:
    print('Deposited $' + str(transaction['amount']) + ' at ' + str(transaction['time']))

print(f'Your final balance is ${init_bal + deposit}.')
```

Comment: Looks great @Maran Sowthri 
I like the datetime touch!!! :)
Thank you heaps!!

Answer (score 2):

```
another = True
init_bal = 1000
deposit = 0
toatl_deposits = []

while another:
    another += 1
    deposit += int(input("Enter amount: "))
    toatl_deposits.append(deposit)
    print(f'${deposit} deposited!')

    another = int(input("Make another deposit? Yes=1, No=2 "))
    if another == 1:
        another = True
    else:
        print(f'Your initial balance was ${init_bal}.')
        print(f'You have deposited a total of ${deposit}.')
        print(f'Your final balance is ${init_bal + deposit}.')
        print('following are list of user inputs: ')
        for i in toatl_deposits:
            print(f'${i}')
        break
```

Comment: I knew it would be something so simple... dang! I should have known better!!! Append of course!!!! A million thanks!!!! @Divyessh

Answer (score 0):

If you write this code by yourself you could understand to easily break it down and print out like this.

```
another = True
init_bal = 1000
deposit = 0
while another:
    another += 1
    amount = input("Enter amount: ")
    deposit += int(amount)
    print("Deposit Amount = " , amount)
    print(f'${deposit} deposited!')    
    another = int(input("Make another deposit? Yes=1, No=2 "))
    if another == 1:
        another = True
    else:
        print(f'Your initial balance was ${init_bal}.')
        print(f'You have deposited a total of ${deposit}.')
        print(f'Your final balance is ${init_bal + deposit}.')
        break
```